# How to pull conditional values from lists inside javascript objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, javascript-objects

I have an object, with a list inside each key. What is the best way of returning the key, if the url string matches what's in the array.

For example in the code below, 'entertainment' would be returned as "/video" is in the entertainment array.

```
const url = "https://example.com/video";

const verticalList = {
    autos:[],
    entertainment:["/video", "/tech"],
    foodanddrink:[],
    healthandfitness:[],
    homepage:["/home"],
    lifestyle:["/ideas", "/executive-life"],
    money:["/money-markets",],
    news:["/briefing"],
    sports:[],
    travel:[],
    weather:[]
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) to get a list of key-value pairs from your object and then run [`Array.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to compare values against your `url`. In the last step you have to run [`Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to retrieve corresponding keys. [String.includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) can be used to check if one string is a substring of another.

```js
const url = "https://example.com/video";

const verticalList = {
    autos:[],
    entertainment:["/video", "/tech"],
    foodanddrink:[],
    healthandfitness:[],
    homepage:["/home"],
    lifestyle:["/ideas", "/executive-life"],
    money:["/money-markets",],
    news:["/briefing"],
    sports:[],
    travel:[],
    weather:[]
}

let matches = Object.entries(verticalList)
                    .filter(([key,value]) => value.some(x => url.includes(x)))
                    .map(([key,value]) => key);

console.log(matches)
```

Comment: Thanks, it works great I don't fully understand what's going on, but I will read up on all these new methods on mozilla!

Comment: @JonathanDevereux sure - it's really good to get familiar with them - they can make your like easier :)